# Rancher desktop is asking system permission on each startup

Tags: macos, installation, startup, rancher

I installed Rancher desktop in order to look for an alternative to Docker Desktop. While starting Rancher Desktop it always asks for permission as follows

```
Rancher Desktop needs root access to configure its internal network by populating the following location:
/var/** some location
```

[image]

what I am looking is that it should not ask for that permission everytime, rather take the permission first time and remember it

Answer (score 12):

open Security and Privacy on mac as shown in below figure and check the checkbox in front of Rancher-Desktop
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. The Rancher team will be releasing a fix for this issue soon: https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/discussions/1814#discussioncomment-2370182

Comment: yep. Doesn't work